# How do I ring my friend's doorbell?

Tags: pattern, no-computers

My friend, a curmudgeon who dislikes visitors, recently installed a puzzle-doorbell. It consists of ten push buttons in a row, labelled from left to right:

`"2"   ","   "3"   ","   "4"   ","   "1"   "o"   "f"   "5"`

(That is, the second, fourth, and sixth buttons are each labelled with a comma.)

Mounted below the buttons is a small plaque that reads:

"Ring bell. (Only misfits need apply.)"

How do I ring my friend's doorbell?

It may or may not be relevant, but my friend's door mat seems to have been woven by someone who can't spell or who kept losing their place in the pattern; it reads:

GGRREETIINNGSS
MAY ALLL BBE WEELLCOMME

Hint:

> You'll have to press eight buttons, none twice.

Hint:

> Take 2, 3, 4, 1 of every 5 of "2 , 3 , 4 , 1 o f 5".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

> ,3,21of,

Method:

> We cut the ten digits in half and then type the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, then 1st character of each, as the sequence tells us to do.  Not sure about the door mat.

Comment: Excellent! (Did I make it too obvious?) ... I'll wait to see if anyone can tell how the door mat corroborates this correct answer.

Comment: For the door mat, there are 10 incorrectly-doubled letters (so not including the EE of GREETING, which is correctly doubled), which in order gives GRINSLBELM.   Applying the 2341 of 5 to these gives RING BELL.